# How to get the xpath of a <b> tag which is designed below the div text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to fetch a text content from a  tag which is located just below a div text named ,'Authors:'.
I have identified the location for 'Authors' but I need to traverse through each block of authors and need to fetch the corresponding text associated with 'Authors' label.I have tried the following but I couldn't get the result.

//table[@id='thdListTable']//td[@class='msgHead']//div[contains(text(), 'Author:')]
//td[@class='msgHead']/div[contains(text(), 'Author:')]

```
<table id="thdListTable" width="95%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="msgHead">
    <div>
     Author: 
     <b>Kurt Wendt <Kurt_Wendt (AT) globetax D.O.T com></b>
     <br/>
     Subject: 
     <b>To Impersonate on MS SQL</b>
     - 
     <a target="_new" href="/archives/msg/501727">Link</a>
     <br/>
     Posted: 
     <b>2015-10-14 11:31:56</b>
     <br/>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//table[@id='thdListTable']//div/b[1]"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to go for the first `b` element that is found below your div, because that should be the author's name, if I understood you correctly.
Then just get the text via `getText()` method

```
string xpathExpression = "//td[@class='msgHead']/div[contains(text(), 'Author:')]/b[1]";
string authorName = driver.findElement(By.xpath()).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can reach to there by using the code

```
//td[@class='msgHead']/div[contains(text(), 'Author:')]/b[1]
```

So you can retrieve the same results for others by changing the text contain name.